# Can IE8 play video without Flash

Tags: flash, video, internet-explorer-8

Basic question really. Is the only option of playing video in IE8 to use Flash, even as a fallback with the HTML5 video for everyone code?

Comment: Thanks Spudely. Corporate client, crappy old browsers, not allowed plug-ins. Oh well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, that's the only real option.

Okay, there are other plugins that could do it, like Silverlight, but the net effect is the same. And yes, as there are [polyfill scripts](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) that attempt to make the browser work with standard HTML5 code, but they're still using flash behind the scenes.

Bottom line is that IE8 does not have native video playing capabilities.